# thymeleaf cannot resolve field in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple form that send an object named `obj` and a value named `description` to my controller and controller post it to my data base. I am using a jpa repository. At first I had a problem for resolving `th:object="${obj}"` in my form but after reading a stack overflow posts I added a var definition for my object and it fixed the problem but I still can't use `th:field` in my input tag and if I just write it, I get 500 internal error. `th:name=` works without any problem but I need to use `th:field` in my project.

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--/*@thymesVar id="obj" type="springframework.controllers.view"*/-->
<form  th:action="@{/p/post}" th:object="${obj}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:name="description" />
<!--<td><input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/></td> error happen here -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/p")
public class view {
    @PostMapping("post")
    public String post(@ModelAttribute("obj")UnitOfMeasure unitOfMeasure){
        unitOfMeasureRepository.save(unitOfMeasure);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

error log

```
ERROR 14380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "post": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/post.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/post.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
```

Comment: Does your entity "UnitOfMeasure" actually have a "description" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before asking for an Object from the Model you need to provide it into the model. Thymeleaf won't do that for you. More here https://javamondays.com/problems-with-thymeleaf/

Comment: you open my eyes! i was look looking in the wrong area.i thought spring boot can do it automatically. i have done like that a long time ago with spring mvc core. thanks for your help i'll post the changes under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

in this case there is no problem with thyme-leaf, error happen because of i didn't add the object to the model

```
 @GetMapping("/m")
    public String vri(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("obj", new UnitOfMeasure());
        return "post";
    }
    @PostMapping("/post")
    public String post(@ModelAttribute("obj") UnitOfMeasure unitOfMeasure, Model model){
       // model.addAttribute("obj", unitOfMeasure);

        unitOfMeasureRepository.save(unitOfMeasure);
        return "home";
    }
```